# Jmeter - Does $ appearing in string break Response Assertion

Tags: json, jmeter

Running some tests where we need to validate that $ appearing in a string does not break the service (having manually tested it, it works fine!).

Converting the tests to be run via Jmeter and the tests including $ are all failing.

Test is structured (and apologies of not being able to post a screenshot of this, but it's all on a secure system):

```
    Http Request to service
      JSON Extractor (returning ValueX from json)
      Response Assertion (comparing ValueX to ValueY)
          Response Field to Test = Response Message
          Pattern Matching Rules = Contains
```

Examples of ValueX and ValueY:

```
ValueX = ["012345","012456","EDB$DE"]
ValueY = "012345","012456","EDB$DE"
```

I'm using the Contains pattern match, so to my mind, the two values above should match, unless I've misunderstood something.

Is Jmeter possibly misinterpreting the $ in the results to be some indication of a new variable?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> 1. a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
> 2. a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

According to [JMeter's Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) user manual chapter:

> Multi-line mode only affects how the meta-characters **'^'** and **'$'** are interpreted.

So you have 2 options:

1. If you are going to continue using "Contains" pattern matching rule you will need to escape the `$` meta character with a back slash like:

   ```
   EDB\$DE
   ```
2. Alternatively you can switch to "Equals" pattern matching rule, in that case you can leave your `EDB$DE` pattern as is

Comment: Thanks @dmitri-t . I've switched the query to use Substring as it definitely appears to be an issue with the $ acting as an escape character. Got a similar set of tests with \ and / in. Those are proving more 'challenging' as escaping the escape character may actually invalidate the test!